"predictable" device names in smartd.conf on various linux-like systems
To configure S.M.A.R.T. monitoring, it's indicated configuration file /etc/smartd.conf should be customized by identifying each device and the smartctl parameters assigned to it, except:

smartctl still uses the slightly unpredictable standard of identifying devices by name [/dev/sda, /dev/sdb, etc.]. Years ago, kernel developers saw the issue with this and switched to better methods of identification, particularly UUID, PARTUUID, and LABEL, but unless I'm missing it, smartctl seems not as "smart" as we would like.
When I start a particular system, the drives that house a RAID configuration may be /dev/<sda - sdh>, but if there happens to be a USB drive inserted at boot, those names will switched to /dev/<sdb - sdi> (if there are two USB drives attached, they might shift more, or on the next boot, they might not).

What are others doing to avoid this and ensure the S.M.A.R.T. configuration is appropriate for the mounted devices? (Please don't suggest leaving the USB slot empty - that's not a reliable solution.)
